# How can I create a DataGridView in a TabPage of 2nd from by clicking the button in the 1st Form

Tags: c#, winforms

This is `Form1`:

```
private void Btn_Create_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 frm2 = new Form2(txt_LedgerName.Text);
    frm2.Show();
}
```

And this is `Form2`:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2(string message)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TabPage tbpg = new TabPage();
        tbpg.Text = message;
        //var dlt = tabControl1.TabPages[0];
        //dlt.Hide();
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tbpg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Create or populate with some data?

Comment: Same way you are doing it.  `DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView(); tbpg.Controls.Add(dgv);`

Comment: Thanku brother ... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this to add a control to a tabPage on Form2 from Form1.

On Form2 create a function:

```
// Adds a control to an existing tab page # or creates a new page if it doesn't exist 
// The value returned will be the actual page number which may not match
// the requested page number.
public int AddControl(int tabPage, Control control)
{
    TabPage tbpg;
    if (tabControl1.TabPages.Count <= tabPage)
        tbpg = tabControl1.TabPages[tabPage];
    else
    {
        tbpg = new TabPage();
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tbpg);
    }
    tbpg.controls.Add(control);
    return tabcontrol1.TabPages.IndexOf(tbpg);
}
```

Comment: i want to add a datagridview on every click on a button in a new tabpage

Comment: On each button_click() you can just call: int pageNum = frm2.Addcontrol(999, myControl); Since there are not 999 pages, it will just create the next available and pageNum will contain the actual tab page number.